# Anylogic: Prioritize different agents for exit the same queue

Tags: java, anylogic

I have 3 sources with 3 **different** agents coming together in the same queue. agent type 1 is prioritized over type 2 and agent type 2 over type 3. How do i get the right order for leaving the queue? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NqH2r.png)

[model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NqH2r.png)

Answer (score 0):

Set the queue priority to "agent comparison". In the field, write:

`(agent1 instanceof AgentType1 || (agent1 instanceof AgentType2 && agent2 instanceof AgentType3)`

this will prioritize Type1 over 2 over 3.

You may need to refine the logic but you get the zest :)